# How to extract some text via bash

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, shell

I have an output:

```
 <artifactId>prj-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.11.1-Beta01-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

How to extract only the 1.11.1-Beta01-SNAPSHOT using linux commands ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use an xml parser.  All of the answers (including the accepted answer) are using a regex to parse xml, which is always a bad idea.

Comment: `always` and `never` are big words. Some would also say that XML itself is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU sed:

```
sed -nr '/<\/?version>/s///gp'
```

Comment: Not quite, this will include white space in front of the tag. Unfortunately `sed -nr '/\s*<\/?version>/s///gp'` destroys white space before the end tag. So we're stuck with `sed -rn 's#.*<(version>)([^<]*)</\1.*#\2#p'`

Comment: Oh... yes. The best version is with GNU grep and perl syntax.

Comment: It is the best solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grep`:

```
  echo $string | grep -P -o '(?<=<version>).*?(?=</version>)'
```

Comment: +1 could you please explain the grep statement - I have never seen such construction before.

Comment: The `-P` option indicates that pattern is a Perl regex, and `(?=pattern)` and `(?<=pattern)` are lookaround assertions (see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions))

Answer (score 3):

```
grep '<version>' | replace "<version>" "" "</version>" ""
```

For one entry per line

Comment: be aware that "replace" is not standard command but utility coming with MySQL package(s)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F '[<>]' '$2 == "version" {print $3}'
```

Comment: This is nice.  Totally non-robust if '<' or '>' occur anywhere in the text, but that is an artifact of trying to parse xml with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
a="<artifactId>prj-parent</artifactId>\n<version>1.11.1-Beta01-SNAPSHOT</version>"
echo $a | grep -oe "<version>.*</version>" | cut -d">" -f2- | cut -d"<" -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

TXR:

```
$ txr -c "@(skip)
 <artifactId>@aid</artifactId>
 <version>@version</version>" data.txt
aid="prj-parent"
version="1.11.1-Beta01-SNAPSHOT"
```

Just `eval` that command and shell variable `version` is set. You can check `aid` for the correct artifact ID. If `txr` doesn't find a match, it will fail and print the word `false`. Under `eval` this `false` will create a failed termination status:

```
if $(txr -c "@(skip)
 <artifactId>@aid</artifactId>
 <version>@version</version>") ; then
  echo "version captured: $version"
else
  echo "failed to match, uh oh!"
fi
```

Extracting XML with TXR is not as ideal as using an XML parser and then accessing the node structure, but it's a heck of a lot more robust than using simple regular expressions that latch onto the minimal amount of context to do the job, and verified with only a small population of examples.

For these kinds of tasks, you don't really have the luxury of software engineering a solution with a rigorous test suite. The variations in the data are not even known in advance, or there may be reams of data (e.g. extracting from big logs) in which mistakes are hard to spot. (If say, 2 out of every 10,000 entries in a log are extracted wrong, will someone catch the bug?)  Data can change too. Tomorrow someone changes the XML and your regex hack pulls out some wrong piece of text as the version.

The best approach is to write very specific matches which allow just for the relevant expected variation among the inputs, and which complain if there is a mismatch.